# Assign permissions to users in Django groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using Django (3) with a custom user model using `BaseAbstractUser` in which I have a BooleanField field named `is_instructor` and also created a group named `instructor`. So when the user signup with `is_instructor` he will have all the permissions of the `instructor` group. And to this group I assigned all the permissions related to my `courses` app in Django admin. Now If I try to create a new course with a user which has `instructor` group permissions it redirect me to incorrect login page, my actual login URL path is `/users/login` but it redirect me to '/accounts/login`.

Here's my Model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    is_instructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_join = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

My signup view:

```
def registration_view(request):
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('get post req')
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            if form.cleaned_data['is_instructor'] is True:
                instructor_group = Group.objects.get(name='instructor')
                instructor_group.user_set.add(user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('users:login'))
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

and here's the view to create a new course:

```
class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)

class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin,
                       LoginRequiredMixin,
                       PermissionRequiredMixin):
    model = Course
    fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview', 'course_img']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')

class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'

class CourseCreateView(OwnerCourseEditMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'courses.add_course'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses:manage_course_list')
```

what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because you have override `has_perm` method

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
```

in user model which is returning True only if `is_admin` is True

remove this method or check properly for `perm` permission.

Comment: can you confirm the `instructor`  group is properly added to the user groups

Comment: yes, I check the database and also Django admin, Group added to the user.

Comment: then there must be some other issue. Can you add some info about the project in question

Comment: for details take a look at the question below, please!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63952503/7644562

Comment: I think the issue is with the `has_pem` method defined in the user model